# Kivy, opacity around mouse, revealing picture

Tags: python, kivy

I would like to make a puzzle where someone has to follow a maze and collect letters which have to be typed in later as an answer. (Not collected by the program but just remembering which letters are passed and typing it in later while exiting the maze.)

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.config import Config

Config.set('graphics', 'width', '806')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '706')

class Touch(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Touch, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        pass

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        pass

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        pass
    
class MyGrid(GridLayout):
    pass
    
class DrawingWindow(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGrid()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    DrawingWindow().run()
```

```
<MyGrid>:
    
    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        size:1000,706

        canvas:
            
            Rectangle:
                size: 808,706
                source: 'Puzzle.png'
```

I have found out how to draw a circle where your mouse is (not added to the code as I think a different method is probably going to be used), but how to make everything around a certain radius  black so that it only reveals a small circle within this radius. Maybe using opacity within a radius is a sollution. If someone could push me in the right direction, that would be really helpful.

It does not have to stay revealed, rather not actually. Hopefully that makes it somewhat easier as well.

I hope I've stated clearly what the problem is. Thank you in advance for the time and effort.

Comment: I think easiest would be a blackened maze background that is always the first part of the view refreshed, then draw your illuminated mouse (with visible background) in its circle.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Stencil Instructions](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.graphics.stencil_instructions.html) to accomplish that. Here is a simple example:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ListProperty
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

kv = '''
RelativeLayout:
    ImageWithHole:
        id: hole
        canvas:
            StencilPush
            Ellipse:  # draw the hole
                pos: self.hole_pos[0] - self.radius, self.hole_pos[1] - self.radius
                size: self.radius*2, self.radius*2
            StencilUse
            Color:
                rgba: 1,1,1,1
            Rectangle:
                source: 'Puzzle.png'  # draw the maze
                pos: 0,0
                size: self.size
            StencilUnUse
            Ellipse:  # erase the hole (must be identical to original draw above)
                pos: self.hole_pos[0] - self.radius, self.hole_pos[1] - self.radius
                size: self.radius*2, self.radius*2
            StencilPop
'''


class ImageWithHole(Widget):
    radius = NumericProperty(50)
    hole_pos = ListProperty([400, 300])


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Window.bind(mouse_pos=self.on_motion)
        return Builder.load_string(kv)

    def on_motion(self, src, mouse_pos):
        hole = self.root.ids.hole
        hole.hole_pos = mouse_pos

TestApp().run()
```

Comment: Dude. Thank you so much. You're amazing. I'm making some kind of puzzle/escape room for my girlfriend so she receives her present in a fun way. Thanks bro.